# Create two different mtext in a single program

Tags: c#, autocad

This is my program in which i can print attribute in the `dwg file` but the problem is that `mtext` print the value like:
Project:534Phase:1Zone:A(0530)
Project:534Phase:1Zone:A(0520) and so on but i want output like
Project:534
Phase:1
Zone:A
(0530)
(0520).

```
[CommandMethod("ATT")]
public void ListAttributes()
{
    Document acDoc = Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument;
    Editor ed = acDoc.Editor;
    Database db = acDoc.Database;
    using (Transaction tr = db.TransactionManager.StartTransaction())
    {
        // Start the transaction
        try
        {
            // Build a filter list so that only
            // block references with attributes are selected
            TypedValue[] filList = new TypedValue[2] { new TypedValue((int)DxfCode.Start, "INSERT"), new TypedValue((int)DxfCode.HasSubentities, 1) };
            SelectionFilter filter = new SelectionFilter(filList);
            PromptSelectionOptions opts = new PromptSelectionOptions();
            opts.MessageForAdding = "Select block references: ";
            PromptSelectionResult res = ed.GetSelection(opts, filter);
            // Do nothing if selection is unsuccessful
            if (res.Status != PromptStatus.OK)
                return;

            SelectionSet selSet = res.Value;

            ObjectId[] idArray = selSet.GetObjectIds();

            PromptPointResult ppr;
            PromptPointOptions ppo = new PromptPointOptions("");
            ppo.Message = "\n Select the place for print output:";
            //get the coordinates from user
            ppr = ed.GetPoint(ppo);
            if (ppr.Status != PromptStatus.OK)
                return;
            Point3d startPoint = ppr.Value.TransformBy(ed.CurrentUserCoordinateSystem);
            Vector3d disp = new Vector3d(0.0, -2.0 * db.Textsize, 0.0);

            HashSet<string> attValues = new HashSet<string>();

            foreach (ObjectId blkId in idArray)
            {
                BlockReference blkRef = (BlockReference)tr.GetObject(blkId, OpenMode.ForRead);
                BlockTableRecord btr = (BlockTableRecord)tr.GetObject(blkRef.BlockTableRecord, OpenMode.ForWrite);

                //ed.WriteMessage("\nBlock: " + btr.Name);

                var curSpace = (BlockTableRecord)tr.GetObject(db.CurrentSpaceId, OpenMode.ForWrite);

                AttributeCollection attCol = blkRef.AttributeCollection;
                foreach (ObjectId attId in attCol)
                {
                    AttributeReference attRef = (AttributeReference)tr.GetObject(attId, OpenMode.ForRead);
                    string str = (attRef.TextString);
                    //ed.WriteMessage("\n" + str);
                    if (attValues.Contains(str))
                        continue;
                    if (btr.Name == "NAL-SCRTAG")
                    {
                        MText mtext = new MText();

                        mtext.Location = startPoint;
                        string file = acDoc.Name;
                        string str1 = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file);

                        Match match = Regex.Match(str1, @"^(\w+-[CSDWM]\d+[A-Z]-.)$");
                        var split = str1.Split('-');
                        string code = split.First();
                        string phase = new string(split.ElementAt(1).Skip(1).Take(1).ToArray());
                        string zone = new string(split.ElementAt(1).Skip(2).Take(1).ToArray());

                        mtext.Contents = ("Project:" + code + "Phase:" + phase + "Zone:" + zone + "(" + str + ")");

                        //ed.WriteMessage(text);
                        curSpace.AppendEntity(mtext);
                        tr.AddNewlyCreatedDBObject(mtext, true);
                        db.TransactionManager.QueueForGraphicsFlush();

                        attValues.Add(str);

                        startPoint += disp;
                    }
                }
            }
            tr.Commit();
        }
        catch (Autodesk.AutoCAD.Runtime.Exception ex)
        {
            ed.WriteMessage(("Exception: " + ex.Message));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I do not misunderstand what you're trying to do, you should separate the different tasks:

- Build the begining of the text to print with the filename (which have
  to match a pattern).
- Add the values of the attribute of the selected
  blocks at the end of the text.
- Print the text as MText in AutoCAD

  ```
  [CommandMethod("ATT")]
  public void ListAttributes()
  {
      Document acDoc = Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument;
      Editor ed = acDoc.Editor;
      Database db = acDoc.Database;

      // build the begining of the text from the filename
      string filename = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(acDoc.Name);
      string pattern = @"^(?<code>\w+)-[CSDWM](?<phase>\d+)(?<zone>[A-Z])-\w+$";
      //  pattern description:
      //  ^(?<code>\w+)   'code' named group: one or more word characters at the begining
      //  -               one hyphen (literal)
      //  [CSDWM]         one alphabetic character (C, S, D, W or M)
      //  (?<phase>\d+)   'phase' named group: one or more digits
      //  (?<zone>[A-Z])  'zone' named group: one alphabetic character
      //  -               one hyphen (literal)
      //  \w+$            one or more world characters at the end
      Match match = Regex.Match(filename, pattern);
      if (!match.Success)
      {
          ed.WriteMessage("\n The document file name does not match the pattern.");
          return;
      }
      var groups = match.Groups;
      string text = $"Project:{groups["code"]} Phase:{groups["phase"]} Zone:{groups["zone"]}";

      // Build a filter list so that only "NAL-SCRTAG"
      // block references are selected
      TypedValue[] filList = new TypedValue[2] { new TypedValue(0, "INSERT"), new TypedValue(2, "NAL-SCRTAG") };
      SelectionFilter filter = new SelectionFilter(filList);
      PromptSelectionOptions opts = new PromptSelectionOptions();
      opts.MessageForAdding = "Select block references: ";
      PromptSelectionResult res = ed.GetSelection(opts, filter);
      // Do nothing if selection is unsuccessful
      if (res.Status != PromptStatus.OK)
          return;

      //get the coordinates from user
      PromptPointOptions ppo = new PromptPointOptions("\n Select the place for print output: ");
      PromptPointResult ppr = ed.GetPoint(ppo);
      if (ppr.Status != PromptStatus.OK)
          return;
      Point3d startPoint = ppr.Value.TransformBy(ed.CurrentUserCoordinateSystem);

      // Start the transaction
      using (Transaction tr = db.TransactionManager.StartTransaction())
      {
          try
          {
              // use a HashSet to avoid duplicated values
              HashSet<string> attValues = new HashSet<string>();

              // add the attributes values at the end of the text
              foreach (ObjectId blkId in res.Value.GetObjectIds())
              {
                  BlockReference blkRef = (BlockReference)tr.GetObject(blkId, OpenMode.ForRead);
                  foreach (ObjectId attId in blkRef.AttributeCollection)
                  {
                      AttributeReference attRef = (AttributeReference)tr.GetObject(attId, OpenMode.ForRead);
                      string str = (attRef.TextString);
                      if (attValues.Add(str)) // returns false if attValues already contains str
                      {
                          text += $" ({str})"; // adds the attribute text string at the end of the text
                      }
                  }
              }

              // add the mText to the current space
              var curSpace = (BlockTableRecord)tr.GetObject(db.CurrentSpaceId, OpenMode.ForWrite);
              MText mtext = new MText();
              mtext.Location = startPoint;
              mtext.Contents = text;
              curSpace.AppendEntity(mtext);
              tr.AddNewlyCreatedDBObject(mtext, true);
              tr.Commit();
          }
          catch (Autodesk.AutoCAD.Runtime.Exception ex)
          {
              ed.WriteMessage(("Exception: " + ex.Message));
          }
      }
  }
  ```